# I want to show custom atrribute in invoice of magento2 by override defaultinvoice.php file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

?php
/**

- Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
- See COPYING.txt for license details.
  */
  declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Digitalaptech\InvoicePdf\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

//use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{
/**
* Core string
*
* @var \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils
*/
protected $string;

```
protected $resource;

protected $resourceCollection;    

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Tax\Helper\Data $taxData,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
    \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filterManager,
    \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
    
) {
    $this->string = $string;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $registry,
        $taxData,
        $filesystem,
        $filterManager,
        $string,
        $resource,
        $resourceCollection,
        $data            
    );
}

/**
 * Draw item line
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function draw()
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $item = $this->getItem();
    $pdf = $this->getPdf();
    $page = $this->getPage();
    $lines = [];

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = [
        [
            // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
            'text' => $this->string->split(html_entity_decode($item->getName()), 35, true, true),
            'feed' => 35
        ]
    ];
    // $lines[0] = [
    //     [
    //         // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
    //         'text' => $this->string->split(html_entity_decode($item->getAttribute('$item')), 35, true, true),
    //         'feed' => 35
    //     ]
    // ];
    //$lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getAttribute('brand') , 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];



    $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = [
        // phpcs:ignore Magento2.Functions.DiscouragedFunction
        'text' => $this->string->split(html_entity_decode($this->getAttribute($item)), 17),
        'feed' => 290,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
    /*$lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $this->string->split($this->getPvp(), 17),
        'feed' => 290,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];
```

*/
// draw QTY
$lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

```
    // draw item Prices
    $i = 0;
    $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
    $feedPrice = 395;
    $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 170;
    foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
        if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
            // draw Price label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
            // draw Subtotal label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
            $i++;
        }
        // draw Price
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['price'],
            'feed' => $feedPrice,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        // draw Subtotal
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
            'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        $i++;
    }

    // draw Tax
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed' => 495,
        'font' => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right',
    ];

    // custom options
    $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
            $lines[][] = [
                'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                'font' => 'italic',
                'feed' => 35,
            ];

            // Checking whether option value is not null
            if ($option['value'] !== null) {
                if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                    $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                } else {
                    $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                }
                $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

    $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $this->setPage($page);
}
```

}